# Mod_rewrite - Multiple rules in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm setting up a slightly more complexed web site than I normally are used to using a bespoke CMS system and have hit a stumbling block.

Basically what I am wanting to achieve is a simple top level page structure so the urls are clean as follows:

http://www.mywebsite.com/page.php?page_url=val1

http://www.mywebsite.com/val1

Not normally a problem, but the existing .htaccess already has several RewriteRules existing and any variation of adding a RewriteRule conflicts and prevents select pages from working.

Tried variations around...

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(.+)
RewriteRule ^$ /%1? [R=301,L]
```

With no joy.

Do I need to rethink my strategy or is there something I'm just quite simply overlooking?

Should I be rethinking towards making the top-level-category page 'market.php' do the work rewriting in the # Specify MARKET LEVEL rewrite

My existing .htaccess is as follows and works fine after a thorough testing but changing to include the new top level page causes it to error.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Force search engines to use www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mywebsite\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
# Specify MARKET LEVEL rewrite
RewriteRule ^top-level-category-1$ /market.php?p=top-level-category-1 [L]
RewriteRule ^top-level-category-2$ /market.php?p=top-level-category-2 [L]
RewriteRule ^top-level-category-3$ /market.php?p=top-level-category-3 [L]
RewriteRule ^top-level-category-4$ /market.php?p=top-level-category-4 [L]
RewriteRule ^top-level-category-5$ /market.php?p=top-level-category-5 [L]
RewriteRule ^top-level-category-6$ /market.php?p=top-level-category-6 [L]
Options +FollowSymLinks
# Specify OFFER LEVEL rewrite
RewriteRule offer/(.*)/ offer.php?p=$1
RewriteRule offer/(.*) offer.php?p=$1
# Specify CLAIM OFFER LEVEL rewrite
RewriteRule get-offer/(.*)/ reveal.php?claim=$1
RewriteRule get-offer/(.*) reveal.php?claim=$1
# Specify CLAIM EVENT LEVEL rewrite
RewriteRule event-bonus/(.*)/ reveal-event.php?claim=$1
RewriteRule event-bonus/(.*) reveal-event.php?claim=$1
# Specify SEARCH LEVEL rewrite
RewriteRule search/(.*)/ search.php?p=$1
RewriteRule search/(.*) search.php?p=$1
# Specify EVENT LEVEL rewrite
RewriteRule offers/(.*)/ offers.php?p=$1
RewriteRule offers/(.*) offers.php?p=$1
# Specify BLOG LEVEL rewrite
RewriteRule blog/(.*)/ blog.php?p=$1
RewriteRule blog/(.*) blog.php?p=$1
RewriteRule view-blog/(.*)/ view-blog.php?p=$1
RewriteRule view-blog/(.*) view-blog.php?p=$1
# Specify EXPIRED OFFER LEVEL rewrite
RewriteRule offer-expired/(.*)/ offer-expired.php?p=$1
RewriteRule offer-expired/(.*) offer-expired.php?p=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this `RewriteRule` in your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /page.php?page_url=$1 [L]
```

It should leave you with your desired URL.

Comment: It doesn't work. Tested it within the existing .htaccess and no page loads

Comment: @Lee what thickguru said should work as it is the proper .htaccess to do as you said. i guess if not then it should be issue on your existing htacees that overrides it or ignores this rule. did you put what he said at top of your htaccess file ?